# Ubuntu Live Flash Drive not booting anymore

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, live-usb, windows-10

**What i did:**

So, i'm using an Asus, AMD Windows 10 and i have installed a ubuntu live image on a Lexar flash drive (with the sole intention of testing ubuntu from time to time, not to install it on my HDD).

I installed an ubuntu live image on the flash drive using Universal-USB-Installer and **it worked** pretty well during the first two weeks (during these weeks i plugged and unplugged the flash drive several times).

This friday, i was leaving the city for the weekend and unplugged the flash drive from my computer (with the computer off). When i came back today (monday) i turned on my computer and used windows for a while and then wanted to use ubuntu. So i turned off my computer, and plugged the flash drive. For my surprise, it booted on windows.

So i shut down my machine again, entereted the BIOS and changed the priority from the hard drive to the "USB Lexar Flash Drive". Saved and exit, and it booted windows again. Tried a few more times always entering the BIOS to check the boot device priority, and it continued to boot on windows.

---

**What is happening:**

I'm finding odd that the LED from the USB is not flashing while i am on the BIOS. However, i don't think this is a flash drive problem, since i'm able to see my flash drive while using windows, it displays on my computer as "UUI (F:)"

I don't what is causing the issue. Any help fixing this is very appreciated.

**EDIT**

I reinstalled the Ubuntu on the flash drive. It didn`t work. Same thing is happening: Can see the flash drive on BIOS, set the priority to it, but it always boot windows.

Comment: This sounds so crazy that I'm afraid to post this as an answer, but it actually works sometimes. When you boot enter your BIOS/UEFI utility for one minute and then exit from BIOS/UEFI without changing anything, and maybe the Ubuntu live USB will boot.

Comment: Can you type Esc at power-up to get the EFI menu, and select the USB from that?  Try another USB port?  Try USB in another machine?

Comment: I tried various USB ports, none of them worked. I will try the EFI menu.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem, took various steps, not shure which one of them (maybe all) led to success, so i'll write a few things i did here:

1. Try Connecting and Disconnecting your pendrive while in the bios/uefi and try boot and reboot.
2. If your pendrive stops being visible at the BIOS (or he already is) turn off your computer completely and disconnect it from power supply. Hold power button for about 5 seconds and then plug in the pen drive. Turn on the computer. (There might me some residual charges in your motherboard's pen drive port, so this proccess actually eliminates it, sounds crazy but i think it helped me).
3. Enter the BIOS again and choose your pen drive on hard disk priority.

These steps worked for me. Hope they help somebody in the future as well. I'll leave the question open in case somebody comes with a better explanation than mine (i'm pretty shure that it exists). Thank you all.